# How to add multiple fields in sharepoint forms as you go?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I am creating a form in sharepoint where a person can request service for one or more people. Sometime the request will be for just one person and sometime it will be for multiple person. Is there any way I can add a button say if a user needs to add another person on his form then creates another set of (Fname, LName, phone and email)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that out of the box in SPOnline and Designer. If it is enabled you could easily achieve that InfoPath (or maybe PowerApps but I don't have enough production experience on the latter to be sure)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as easy as it might sound as you really need to know how many possible items (rows) the user potentially would want to add. Think of excel, you can add a huge amount of rows to the table, but eventually you will reach the limit.

When I face this kind of requirement from clients I try to split the data into a parent and a child table linking them together using a lookup column.

This way I can have the parent item with the static information and I'm able to add an (almost) infinite amount of child items (or rows if you will) to the parent item. It does require a bit of tinkering to get it really userfriendly, but the end result if often a lot better than adding say 10 options just to be sure, the form contains enough fields for the user.

Answer (score -1):

Seems similar requirement as [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b18056f2-5ce4-418b-98a3-cea9e5d60f82/jquery-clone-repeater-parentchild-association-issues-to-save-sp-list?forum=sharepointdevelopment#f2b5e49c-6890-4d8d-8456-72f8479d107e), if so, you could create custom form and save data to list by JavaScript&jQuery with JSOM.